# Flans Mod keeps crashing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Whenever I spawn in vehicles in Flans mod 1.7.2, my game crashes. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is the crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// You're mean.

Time: 9/12/14 1:56 PM
Description: Ticking entity

java.lang.NullPointerException: Ticking entity
    at com.flansmod.common.driveables.EntityVehicle.func_70071_h_(EntityVehicle.java:412)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72866_a(World.java:2101)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72866_a(WorldServer.java:674)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72870_g(World.java:2064)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72939_s(World.java:1916)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72939_s(WorldServer.java:512)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71190_q(MinecraftServer.java:658)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:569)
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71217_p(IntegratedServer.java:114)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:454)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer$2.run(MinecraftServer.java:706)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at com.flansmod.common.driveables.EntityVehicle.func_70071_h_(EntityVehicle.java:412)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72866_a(World.java:2101)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72866_a(WorldServer.java:674)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72870_g(World.java:2064)

-- Entity being ticked --
Details:
    Entity Type: Vehicle (com.flansmod.common.driveables.EntityVehicle)
    Entity ID: 880754
    Entity Name: Panzer IV
    Entity's Exact location: -258.50, 64.50, -50.50
    Entity's Block location: World: (-259,64,-51), Chunk: (at 13,4,13 in -17,-4; contains blocks -272,0,-64 to -257,255,-49), Region: (-1,-1; contains chunks -32,-32 to -1,-1, blocks -512,0,-512 to -1,255,-1)
    Entity's Momentum: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72939_s(World.java:1916)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72939_s(WorldServer.java:512)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: WW2 DEATHMATCH
    All players: 1 total; [EntityPlayerMP['Sparrow'/224, l='WW2 DEATHMATCH', x=-258.03, y=63.00, z=-48.22]]
    Chunk stats: ServerChunkCache: 605 Drop: 0
    Level seed: -6197332649445610733
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: true
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (-277,64,-43), Chunk: (at 11,4,5 in -18,-3; contains blocks -288,0,-48 to -273,255,-33), Region: (-1,-1; contains chunks -32,-32 to -1,-1, blocks -512,0,-512 to -1,255,-1)
    Level time: 22665 game time, 22665 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x04ABD - Anvil
    Level weather: Rain time: 13895 (now: true), thunder time: 5366 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: creative (ID 1). Hardcore: false. Cheats: true
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71190_q(MinecraftServer.java:658)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:569)
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71217_p(IntegratedServer.java:114)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:454)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer$2.run(MinecraftServer.java:706)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.2
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.7.0_21, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 17719944 bytes (16 MB) / 233242624 bytes (222 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G
    AABB Pool Size: 4794 (268464 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 4257 (238392 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 13, tallocated: 95
    FML: MCP v9.01-pre FML v7.2.129.1047 Minecraft Forge 10.12.0.1047 4 mods loaded, 4 mods active
    mcp{8.09} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    FML{7.2.129.1047} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.7.2-10.12.0.1047.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    Forge{10.12.0.1047} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.7.2-10.12.0.1047.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    flansmod{4.3.0} [Flan's Mod] (Flans-Mod-1.7.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available->Available->Available->Available
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 3562 (199472 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 3014 (168784 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Player Count: 1 / 8; [EntityPlayerMP['Sparrow'/224, l='WW2 DEATHMATCH', x=-258.03, y=63.00, z=-48.22]]
    Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'</pre>
```

Comment: The fact that you're getting a NullPointerException in the mod code leads me to believe it's just a poorly coded mod. Contact the mod author and submit a bug report.

Comment: Flan's Gun Mod is not badly coded, its used by many people with no problems.

Comment: Could i check if you have Optifine installed? Optifine may sometines cause this issue out of the blue.

Comment: The only mod I had installed was Flans mod, so there shouldn't be a problem. Are there any codes I should change? Should I update forge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they said first you want to submit a Bug Report to the mod creator. Secondly I have had a similar problem with other mods try un-installing the mod and make sure you are using the most recent version if not then download the most recent and install the mod again, but make sure all the files are in the right folders/files then you should be good. Hope this helps you out man.